# How to activate a conda environment within a PowerShell ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, conda, remote-access, miniconda

I'm looking to run/administer Miniconda remotely using PowerShell. On the remote PC, Miniconda3 was installed using:

```
Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /RegisterPython=1 /AddToPath=1 /S /D=%UserProfile%\Miniconda3
```

Note the option `/AddToPath=1` adds `conda` to the `PATH` environment variable.

On that remote computer, create a conda environment with PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherpc -ScriptBlock {conda create -n py36 python=3.6}
```

Cool, that worked:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherpc -ScriptBlock {conda env list}

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3
py36                     C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\envs\py36
```

However, the new environment cannot be simply activated:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherpc -ScriptBlock {
>>  conda activate py36
>>  conda info
>> }

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\user1\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.8.5
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user1\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user1\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.5 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I've tried adding `conda init` at the start of the ScriptBlock, and this only adds "no change" to various shell files, including a few `*.ps1` files, but does not fix anything.

How should a conda environment be activated within a PowerShell ScriptBlock?

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but for POSIX shells, the `conda init` only creates code to be run during shell initialization - it does not actually run those commands. Assuming it is analogous on PowerShell, you likely need to source the script `miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1` in your session to enable the `conda activate` command. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to register a PowerShell session configuration with a start-up script that was previously configured by `conda init`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherpc -ScriptBlock {
  Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name UserProfile -StartupScript %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
}
# restart afterward
Get-Service -ComputerName otherpc -Name WinRM | Restart-Service
```

This only needs to be done once, and is stored in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Plugin\UserProfile
```

---

Now use `-ConfigurationName UserProfile` with subsequent `Invoke-Command`, e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName otherpc -ConfigurationName UserProfile -ScriptBlock {
  conda activate py36
  conda info
}
```